# How to choose YouTube resolution using Mobile version (m.youtube.com), not desktop nor app

Tags: settings, youtube, screen-resolution

On an android phone, using Firefox, I access the YouTube.Com website.

But for resolution control, I am content when YouTube delivers "m.youtube.com".   I know how to force FireFox to solicit the desktop version.

I note that the desktop web page (during video playback) allows me to adjust the video resolution with the settings/gear, but when using the m.youtube version, I have no means to adjust the playback.  I am also aware that I could log into YouTube/Google, and record my resolution choice.

For privacy reasons:  I choose not to use the YouTube application; I clear retained info on closing FireFox; I avoid the desktop webpage on my android phone since everything gets ridiculously tiny, and; I do not log in to YouTube or Google.

1. Does anyone know of a way to force the resolution low (rather than auto) on m.youtube.com?
2. Does anyone know of a way to view the resolution that youtube delivers on m.youtube.com?
3. If I play one video on the standard desktop and select a particular resolution setting there, will it carry over to subsequent views on m.youtube.come ?

I note that:

- The m.youtube site does not have a resolution selection in the
  settings section of the vertical-3-dots
- On video playback, the m.youtube does not provide a gear on playback.

Thanks !

Comment: You could try using [NewPipe](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.schabi.newpipe/) if you aren't willing to use the official app. This lets you choose the quality level.

Comment: I had wanted to avoid apps, altogether, for this purpose.   I will look-see at the referenced app, in any case.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and just figured it out. I hope the pictures work!

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: Photos are not searchable as "answers". While I believe that you believe these images are an "answer", I similarly believe that this technique should never draw traction as an "acceptable answer for stackexchange.com". Please take the few moments to solidify your answer as TEXT.

Comment: Hmm.   I wonder if that is an amendment to the interface on the desktop, since I originally wrote the question.